# Urllib Password and Username input

Tags: python, http, urllib2, urllib

Im making a program that takes my grades and makes them my background but the site im getting my grade info from is password protected is there any way to use urllib to get into my account and the print the source

this is the HTML

```
<label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="fieldAccount" name="account" value="" size="39"  />
<label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="pw" value="" size="39"  />
```

This is the code im trying to use

```
import urllib2
import urllib



url = 'https://ps.rsd.edu/public/home.html'
values = {'account':'my_username', 'pw':'my_password'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
opener = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print(res)
```

what am i doing wrong!?

Comment: What response did you get? Seems your url is wrong, I check the page and the form action is /guardian/home.html

Comment: The form they post to login has so many hidden fields that trying to do the post yourself is probably not a good idea